# Changing from debug to release in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I've **copied** a debug build onto a IIS 7 server.  If I change

```
<compilation debug="false"/>
```

to "**true**" is that sufficient to change the website into release mode or will I have to do it in Visual Studio, rebuild and publish/copy the website again?

Comment: As far as I know you have to change the `Solution Configuration` to `Release` in visual studio, then build and republish the website again.

Comment: Also, if you set the project to release mode before you publish, that improves the performance of your ASP.NET application.

Comment: The compilation element only affects code in your `.aspx` and `.cshtml/.vbhtml` files. Not the assemblies that your project builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Suggestion will be go back and change it in the visual studio.
It is not only the config change. Debug mode also include more code and PDB file for debugging purpose. in Dubug mode your code will run slow as the code will be less optimized.

You can refer below url for more information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

Comment: The tag compilation is enough to say 'no' to the answer. Changing the flag to 'false' is not going to got back and regenerate assemblies with debug set as 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

#### Set the Project to Release Mode Before You Publish

To set the project to release mode, follow these steps:

1 Right-click **Solution** in Solution Explorer, and then point to **Properties**.

2 Click the **Configuration Properties** folder in the left pane.

3 Click the name of the project in the right pane, and then click **Release** on the **Configuration** dropdown menu.

4 Click **OK**.